# why do i keep geting this unity 2d c# error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling

I'm making a basic unity 2d c# and im making a system that detects what tool your holding  I'm getting only two errors but they are very weird, they are: "Assets\clicked.cs(7,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'spriteRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and "Assets\clicked.cs(7,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'spriteRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

here's the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class clicked : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image Image;
    player sprite; spriteRenderer.sprite

    void Start()
    {
        image = GetComponent<Image>();
        String tool;
        image.gameObject.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(HandleClick);
    }

    void HandleClick()
    {
        tool = sprite.name;

    }
}
```

Comment: The type is `SpriteRenderer` not `spriteRenderer`.

Comment: It's always helpful to refer to the [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
public Image Image;
//This line changed
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

void Start()
{
    image = GetComponent<Image>();
    String tool;
    image.gameObject.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(HandleClick);
}

void HandleClick()
{
    tool = spriteRenderer.sprite.name;

}
```

You used `spriteRenderer` instead of `SpriteRenderer`
and the declaration of the sprite was weird... (not how you need to do it)

Comment: i feel like an idoit rrn but what do i have to change to get this working

Comment: The SpriteRenderer line basically, but you can just copy this as is to your code and it supposed to word